# fixing the entire HTML page on mobile

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a way to fix a page in mobile so that it doesn't move around? I'm trying to pick up the coordinates of when the user touchstarts and touchends but the page moves around, when you touch/swipe etc. You can see it here:

http://machinas.com/wip/esprit/Projects-2014/xmas-game-2014/interaction5/

I'm testing on Iphone5

Answer (score 0):

Try setting overflow to hidden on both the document and the body like this:

```
html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I just sent the prototype to my 5c and it doesn't scroll at all in Safari or Chrome. Did you find a fix?